# Asus P8Z77-V LX RAM Annoying RAM

Tags: memory, motherboard

I'm trying to setup my 2x Corsair 8gb RAM (16gb) on that mobo but for some annoying reason the dual channel aint working. Here's what i did so far

(All the following tests WERE DONE in a wood plate also).

Cleared CMOS RTC Between all tests
Upgraded BIOS to its latest version.

- Used 1 stick on DIMM A1: Failed.
- Used 1 stick on DIMM A2: Failed.
- Used 1 stick on DIMM B1: Success.
- Used 1 stick on DIMM B2: Sucess.
- Used 2 sticks (B1/B2): Success.
- Used 2 sticks (A2/B2): Failed
- Used 2 sticks (A1/B1): Failed

Repeated all the tests with 2x 4gb, same results.
For some reason DIMM A ain't working, pressed memok dozen of times on all configurations, no luck.

I've been googling seems like this mobo got a crapload of problems, did anyone know how to fix that? As I bought this mobo while traveling to USA im not sure if i can RMA that to Asus.

Comment: ASUS and Corsair often causes issues. Make sure the RAM was tested by ASUS and is listed in Memory list for your motherboard.

Comment: It does appear on QVL.

Comment: A good start may be to call ASSU support. At least they could advise on an RMA if possible. It sounds like a cruddy board and if your research shows "crapload of problems" then you may be fighting an unwinnable battle to get it to work. Swap it for a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Finding a replacement board that meets your needs is likely the best course of action.

I would recommend the Asus Sabertooth Z77, if you can find one.  The board comes with a 5 year warranty as does all products in the TuF line.  Note that it does have the same drawbacks as most manufacturers, in that there is a QVL for memory/SSDs/etc.

Comment: This is really more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: Fine, answer simplified and changed.

Comment: "I've been googling seems like this mobo got a crapload of problems, did anyone know how to fix that? "   Hence my reply of finding a new board.   Of course he can RMA the board, and get a replacement board if ASUS allows, BUT if the RAM set is not part of the QVL, and is known to be an issue, there is a chance that other issues will crop up.

Comment: Your suggestion should have been submitted as a comment not an answer.  If you want to suggest an RMA provide more substance to your answer.

Comment: @Ramhound  Do you have any links that would clarify what exactly qualifies as an answer and what qualifies as a comment?  Or are you going by your personal viewpoint on this matter?

Comment: @DavidNazzaro two other people came to the same conclusion as I did.  Why are you calling me out instead of them, my comment, was submitted from the same review queue.  "Finding a replacement board that meets your needs is likely the best course of action." should have been a comment to the question.  3 year old question with 2014 hardware recommendation....

Comment: Two other people sharing opinions is just that a total of three people with opinions.  Yall have yours, I have mine.  Opinions are not facts.  I deal in facts.  Is there somewhere in Meta that describes the difference between what an Answer is and what a Suggestion is?  If so direct me to it so I may enlighten myself as to the nuances of the two.  If not.....

Comment: @DavidNazzaro Question should have been closed 3 years ago in my opinion due to it being broad, I honestly, can't determine what the authors question was.  "Does anyone know how to fix that" isn't an on topic question...

Comment: As he stated before that, that the board was buggy, he apparently wanted to know if anyone could fix a board known to be buggy.  Hence, get a new board.    When you deal with people who have a shaky grasp on English grammar and sentence structure on a daily basis, you tend to figure out what people mean pretty easily.  Didn't see at first it was three years old..............why isn't there something like a TTL for questions?

Comment: @DavidNazzaro,  There are tons on threads on Meta and links in the site help that get into what differentiates good answers vs. comment fodder.  But really, the bottom line is that the site is moderated by the community.  Experienced users review often thousands of posts, and the site relies on collective judgement.  Your answer is premised on the board needing replacement.  You might be right, but your answer doesn't state concrete facts that you base it on; as it stands it's opinion.  That's probably the best anyone can do with the info given, which is what makes the question a poor one.

Comment: @fixer1234  Yeah, I see that.  I vote close this question if possible lol.  Not really a "poor" question, just a question lacking needed details.   I would say I stated my replacement view based on the fact he tested the ram in different slots. I am assuming he first found a working slot, and tested all dimms in that one, then took all known working dimms, and started trying pairs of slots.  But again, assume ass+u+me right?